# Null pointer exception in JavaFX line chart

Tags: javafx-2

I using a JavaFX LineChart in my Swing application and when try to clear the series data i get this exception.

My code just call the clear method, the call is made in the JavaFX thread using Platform.runLater, i using 1.7.0_09 on ubuntu, is there any problems with my code or is this a bug in JavaFX.

```
series.getData().clear();
```

series is an XYChart.Series object

```
Exception in runnable
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafx.scene.chart.LineChart.dataItemRemoved(LineChart.java:275)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.dataItemsChanged(XYChart.java:470)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.access$2500(XYChart.java:72)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series$1.onChanged(XYChart.java:1462)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:134)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:48)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.callObservers(ObservableListWrapper.java:97)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.clear(ObservableListWrapper.java:184)
```

Comment: are you using javafx in siwng app or swing in javafx app ?

Comment: JavaFX in a swing application, JavaFx chart is placed in a JFXPanel

Comment: Afaik this has nothing to do with mixing swing and JavaFX. (Seemingly) random NullPointerExceptions occur while clearing charts in pure JavaFX as well. The only workaround I'm aware of is replacing the series with an empty one.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is now solved, it seems it is a bug of JavaFX.

I have solved by adding

`lineChart.setAnimated(false);` and it all works fine. In JIRA Kenai it has been proposed as bug by commenting `lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);`

This also works but I think it is not the right answer, I can use `.setCreateSymbols(false)` or `(true)` having setted `setAnimated(false);`